# Where should linux shell/ windows bat scripts go in a maven source hierarchy?

Tags: maven

My maven project has launchers written in bash shell and windows bat format.

Where should items like these go in the maven hierarchy?

maybe

```
module/src/main/resources
or
module/src/main/scripts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going with

```
module/src/main/scripts
```

as it is mentioned on maven's website.